# Dockerizing Spring Boot db error : connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker

an spring boot app can run from console A., but I get **connection refused** when it runs by docker run B.

A. from console it works

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=loc -jar app.war
```

B. Dockerfile

```
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=loc" app
ENTRYPOINT java -jar $WDIR/app.war
```

Why I get this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Csaba

Comment: can you login to the container and see if you can reach the database manually? this seems like a networking issue to me

Comment: What's the error?  How do you configure the database location?  Where is the database actually located?  Assuming it's on the same system somewhere, the host name to reach it will be different if the application is running on the host or in a container.

Comment: You are right guys, docker run needs something similar docker run -p 5432:5432  (it doesnt work but since Im new to Docker I forgot to set anything the open the ports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your application properties/yaml for network access. For example; if you have database connection in properties you need check access of database. If you have container database you need to access via container name or for external remote access you can explore [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers)

Comment: thanks for your answer, pls see my comment above